# Typescript Infer literals from data

Tags: typescript

Consider following example:

```
type ArrayMember<T> = T extends Array<infer Member> ? Member : T;

const data = [
    {
        key: 1,
        value: 'some value'
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        value: 'another value'
    }
]

type ResultType = ArrayMember<typeof data>

// Inferred type "ResultType" is:
// type ResultType = {
//     key: number;
//     value: string;
// }
```

I'm looking for the way how to get result like this:

```
type ResultType = {
    key: 1 | 2;
    value: 'some value' | 'another value'
}
```

Is it even possible or is it already beyond typescript possibilities? If so I wonder how? :)

Comment: What's wrong with writing the type like you did at the end?

Comment: @kabanus Maintainability, I'd assume. Grouping dependencies together is good practice to make updates at one place be reflected everywhere else. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a good principle.

Comment: @Chase I'm not sure how that applies here? Writing the `ResultType` explicitly seems to be less verbose and more concise (encapsulating the fact you are writing an actual type), unless there is only a singleton to work with, which I'm guessing is not the case and defeats the purpose.

Comment: @kabanus 1. It applies due to the fact that `ResultType` is inherently dependent on a source, a source that may change. 2. I'm sure it'd not be less verbose when the source type contains many more keys, since `keyof` exists to shorten the manual picking anyway. 3. Using type constructors and computational logic (when needed) to write out types is still "writing an actual type" - just in the same way a naive type definition is also an actual type. If the type system gives you tools to construct types - no reason not to go ham with them, right? :D

Comment: @Chase Well I'm partially convinced due to (1) - if the type is dependent on an external source I agree. It just seems odd to me, since your solution involved changing the source to a constant (though granted, it may be sent by something in OPs control), and in fact, (2) listing out the keys anyway, but with the types not grouped. With your point (3) I agree completely, I did not dispute the 'actuality', just the explicitness. No need to force cool language features if they don't fit with what you're doing (maybe they do here, just as a general rule). Beyond is a matter of taste I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if your source structure actually has the type information **saved as literals**. You can make it do so by using [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

So if you do-

```
const data = [
    {
        key: 1,
        value: 'some value'
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        value: 'another value'
    }
] as const;
```

You'll notice that `typeof data` looks like-

```
type DataType = readonly [{
    readonly key: 1;
    readonly value: "some value";
}, {
    readonly key: 2;
    readonly value: "another value";
}]
```

The type information is persisted at a literal level. Now you can obtain the type of `key` using-

```
type DataType = typeof data;
type Foo = DataType[number]['key'];
// ^ The type is 1 | 2
```

Knowing all of this, you can achieve your desired result by doing-

```
type DataType = typeof data;
type ResultType = Pick<DataType[number], 'key' | 'value'>
```

Try it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAsAKBvmAb1wNJgGsBTATwC4YBGAGhLPwDcEAbAV0voDkEEAFtKMTr0oDW+AL4s8BYkrZU6MAEyK2Hbn0EIwIKAAtKAJwn7psmHJi4AujAQQYoSFFy4o1AA7iACJICAAqAeLofoEgAGbwoQDcvpEwAEqUEDxcUBGBaDAACgCWwOQAPCHI+ZQYYDwiAEaWTkwwAuoCMAA+HZJ8AgB8uAD0ozAAejCmIOyWM5aUQA).

It should be noted that applying `as const` over the whole array will make each property `readonly`.

If you don't want that, you can either apply `as const` to each property value one by one, or just get rid of them using mapped types and the `-readonly` qualifier-

```
type DataType = typeof data;
type ReadonlyResultType = Pick<DataType[number], 'key' | 'value'>;
type ResultType = {
  -readonly [K in keyof ReadonlyResultType]: ReadonlyResultType[K]
}
```

Try it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAsAKBjAb133wGsBTATwC4YBGAGmJIDcEAbAV3NoHIIQAW3Iw2Xcr2YBfJnkLMyVWgCZZJUR258EYEFAAW5AE4bxkuVNwBdGAggxQkKLlxRKABxEARJAgAqHiLobp4gAGbwvgDcroEwAErkCHDg7JSJEJzsUAGeaDAACgCWwKQAPD7IueQYYJyCAEbGVgwwvBSUvDAAPm1i3LwAfDE4ISIZWTlx6ERyALRGSSlgaZgA0jBFYDAd4QlLqenkmdnVVrSJyYcTp4EYa1a4ljgA9C8wAHow+iAsxt-GchAA)

Comment: Wonderful, that is what I was looking for! Thanks for help